# Despertar procesos con signal en C

Tags: c

Tengo dos procesos hijos de un mismo padre, y quiero que no hagan nada hasta que un signal *SIGUSR1* despierte uno u otro.

```
pid1=fork();
if (pid1>0)
{
    pid2=fork();
}
```

¿Qué se emplearía? ¿Quizás `pause()`? ¿Cómo lo reactivaría después?

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que estamos trabajando bajo un sistema UNIX, y que por lo tanto lo que buscas es realizar un tratamiento de señales. Para ello debes añadir información a tu proceso para pedirle que capture un tipo de señal concreta, y que al hacerlo, ejecute una función.

Te pego un pequeño ejemplo de cómo hacer esto, donde:

**mi_handler** es la función que va a ejecutarse cuando reciban una señal (en este ejemplo todas las señales que capturan ejecutan la misma función

**signal** es la función que asocia la señal y la función que queremos ejecutar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void mi_handler(int sig){
int i;
        for (i=10;i>=0;i--){
                printf("<%d> %d\n",sig,i);
                sleep(1);
        }
}

void main()
{
        if (signal(SIGINT, mi_handler) == SIG_ERR){
                printf("Error al asignar tratamiento a SIGINT\n");
                exit (-1);
        }
        if (signal(SIGQUIT, mi_handler) == SIG_ERR){
                printf("Error al asignar tratamiento a SIGQUIT\n");
                exit (-1);
        }

        while (1){
                printf("Sigo durmiendo\n");
                sleep(10);
        }
        exit (0);
}
```